# I can't get my update query to work (php / mysqli)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am posting a shortened version of the form and updating lines. I will truly appreciate any help. I have spent the last 48 hours trying all I could think of and it's driving me insane. If I remove the line if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"), the program runs on loading the page and does update the table at the ID in the url with a blank field. Thanks in advance. Here's the code:

```
<?php   
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
Echo '<form action="editone.php" method="POST">
    Enter new name:<input type="text" name="namex" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update List" /> </form>';

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
$dblink = "nn000185_manager";
$cxn = new mysqli("localhost","user","password", $dblink);
$details = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $_POST['namex']);
$numb = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $id);
$query = "UPDATE  EDITORES SET nom_edit = '$details' WHERE  edit_id =   $numb";
mysqli_query($cxn, $query);
echo $query;
}
?>
```

Comment: I mean when I hit the submit button, it simply won't update the records. The row fields stay the same. Thanks for your time and help!!

Comment: What error you have?

Answer (score 0):

I think your form action didn't pass id.

```
<form action="editone.php" method="POST">
```

If you're using this **single file** as *form editor* and *action*, your form editor URL should be http://localhost/editone.php?id=1

Try to change your form action to

```
<form action="editone.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'" method="POST">
```

or just leave the action blank

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - maybe I'm way off base here but I see the following problems.

1) Your method is POST however your id is coming from GET.
2) I don't see where the id is coming from. It could be coming from somewhere and not posted but I don't see it.

Have you checked to verify the value is actually being passed through to the php?

try this

```
echo "GET = " . var_dump($_GET); 
echo "<br><br>";
echo "POST = " . var_dump($_POST);
exit();
```

Post the results and then post where the id is coming from if you can't figure it out still. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
$query = "SELECT now_edit, FROM EDITORIES WHERE edit_id='$numb' LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your page is being called initially from an anchor link on another page which is why you are getting the `id` from `$_GET['id']`.

When the user presses the submit button of course the form is being submitted as a POST so all the data will be in $_POST, therefore $_GET['id'] will fail and should be generating an error message.

You need to save the $_GET['id'] from the first instantiation so you can use it when the form is posted to you. So put it in a `hidden` field that will be posted to you with the post

```
<?php   
  session_start();
  $user = $_SESSION['user'];
  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET") {
      if ( isset($_GET['id']) ) {
        $id = $_GET['id']); 
      } else {
        // no param passed, could be a hack
        header('Location: some_error_page.php');
        exit;
      }

      echo '<form action="editone.php" method="POST">';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '">';
      echo 'Enter new name:<input type="text" name="namex" />';
      echo '<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update List" /></form>';
  }

  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
      $dblink = "nn000185_manager";
      $cxn = new mysqli("localhost","user","password", $dblink);
      $details = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $_POST['namex']);
      $numb = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $_POST['id']);
      $query = "UPDATE  EDITORES SET nom_edit = '$details' WHERE  edit_id =  $numb";
      mysqli_query($cxn, $query);
      echo $query;
  }
?>
```